# Find the volume of a bounded region rotated about the $x$-axis

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

### Question

A region is bounded by the $x$-axis, $y=x^2-9$ and $y=x^2-4$, where the region looks similar to a u-shape. The region is then rotated about the $x$-axis. Find the volume of the solid formed.[image]

### My Working

We can see that $y=x^2-9$ intersects the $x$-axis at $-3$ and $3$, while $y=x^2-4$ intersects the $x$-axis at $-2$ and $2$. The volume should be

\begin{align}
V&=\pi\left[\int^3_{-3}(x^2-9)^2dx-\int^2_{-2}(x^2-4)^2dx\right]\\
&=2\pi\left[\int^3_0 (x^4-18x^2+81) dx-\int^2_0(x^4-8x^2+16) dx\right]\\
&=2\pi\left\{\left[\frac{x^5}{5}-6x^3+81x\right]^3_0-\left[\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{8x^3}{3}+16x\right]^2_0\right\}\\
&=2\pi\left(\frac{243}{5}-162+243-\frac{32}{5}+\frac{64}{3}-32\right)\\
&=2\pi\left(49+\frac{209}{5}+\frac{64}{3}\right)\\
&=2\pi\cdot\frac{735+627+320}{15}\\
&=2\pi\cdot\frac{1682}{15}=\frac{3364}{15}\pi
\end{align}

But my teacher said the answer was $$\frac{3376}{15}\pi$$

Could anyone please point out where I got the answer wrong? Thank you!

Comment: The quantity in parentheses is $ \ \frac{1688}{15} \ \ . $

Comment: $243-32 \neq 209$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField  Thanks -- I re-evaluated the expression, but didn't check the fractions in the next line term-by-term.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Oops, I must have read the numbers wrong - thank you for helping!

Comment: It's better to do the calculations by hand: you learn a lot more. A French mathematician said: "we do not learn mathematics in a black box"("On n'apprend pas les mathématiques dans une boîte noire.") :)

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen I actually did do all the sums in my head, so that was why I made a mistake :\

Comment: The best way to do math is to make mistakes and then reflect on your mistakes; you should be happy to make mistakes :).

Answer (score 3):

After looking at CyclotomicField's comment, it seems that the teacher's answer is right and that I have just made a silly mistake, as shown below:

\begin{align}
V&=2\pi\left(49+\frac{211}{5}+\frac{64}{3}\right)\\
&=2\pi\cdot\frac{735+633+320}{15}\\
&=2\pi\cdot\frac{1688}{15}=\frac{3376}{15}\pi
\end{align}

Comment: Could you provide a drawing of the region ?

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Okay, I'll post it into the question.

Comment: It would be sufficient in $\Bbb R^2$, perhaps difficult in $\mathbb R^3$.